# JavaPoet - get generic type

Tags: java, android, annotations, javapoet

I'm playing around with annotation processor and JavaPoet. I have a method which I annotated with @MyAnno:

```
@MyAnno
Observable<MyClass> get(int id);
```

I want to generate a class which will have a method:

```
AsyncSubject<MyClass> get(int id);
```

What I've done so far is:

```
ClassName classAsyncSubject = ClassName.get("rx.subjects", "AsyncSubject");
TypeName newReturnType = ParameterizedTypeName.get(classAsyncSubject, get(executableElement.getReturnType()));
```

which gives me:

```
AsyncSubject<Observable<MyClass>>
```

How to get only MyClass?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your returned type always is an `Observable<X>`, you might cast the result from `get(executableElement.getReturnType())` to `ParameterizedTypeName` and access the first type argument:

```
((ParameterizedTypeName) get(executableElement.getReturnType()).typeArguments.get(0)
```

Type, capacity and sanity checks apply.